# Rails select_tag with html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `select_tag` with `options_for_select` containing a collection but would like to prepend an option made up of html

So i have

```
 <nav role="select">
   <%= select_tag "category_filter", options_for_select(@categories.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id, data: { :filter => '.' + c.name.delete(' ') }] }), prompt: 'Select Category' %>
</nav>
```

But I would like my first option to be

```
"<option value='All' data-filter='*' class='show-all'>All</option>"
```

Can I merge the two together somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 <nav role="select">
   <%= select_tag "category_filter", "<option value='All' data-filter='*' class='show-all'>All</option>" + options_for_select(@categories.collect{ |c| [c.name, c.id, data: { :filter => '.' + c.name.delete(' ') }] }), prompt: 'Select Category' %>
</nav>
```

Since [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) return a string of options, you can just concatenate the two.

Also, I would put this option generation logic in a view helper :).

Comment: had to add `.html_safe` at the end of the first option to make it work but going to move to a helper anyway

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be resolved easily by adding the array `['All', 'All', data: {filter: '*'}]` at the first position of the array passed as argument of the `options_for_select`, using `Array#unshift`.

(That is a lot of arrays).

But that way, your code will become a lot confusing.. And as this logic should absolutely not be in the view, I encourage you to take a look to the presenter pattern (http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/09/26/presenting-the-rails-presenter-pattern/).

Here is a simplified example :

Add a presenter :

```
class CategoriesPresenter
  def initialize(categories)
    @categories = categorie
  end

  def select_options
    categories_options.unshift(all_option)
  end

  private

  def categories_options
    @categories.collect do |c| 
      [c.name, c.id, data: { :filter => '.' + c.name.delete(' ') }] }
    end
  end

  def all_option
    ['All', 'All', data: {filter: '*'}]
  end
end
```

then in your controller :

```
@categories = CategoriesPresenter.new(categories)
```

and in your view :

```
options_for_select(@categories.select_options)
```